# Inline if statement and return

Tags: javascript, syntax

I have a function that I'm trying to optimize at the moment but I'm running into some issues.

The function will be called a lot of times, so I'm trying to make it so that the returned value is quickly determined and that the next call begins.

(By quickly determined I mean not having a single `return` statement at the end of the function.)

This is the simplified code :

```
function myFunction(letr) {
    if (letr === " ") return var letc = " ";
    // ... other checks on letr that will return other values for letc
}
```

The issue is that the 2nd line doesn't seem to be valid JavaScript.

How can this be written the right way + optimized ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: you can use ternary operator to optimize your function

Comment: @Nudier you can't `return` from a ternary ... :)

Comment: Why do you need the letc variable? Why not simply do a `return " "`?

Comment: Yeah, I already use the ternary operator later in this function but when there is no "else" (or ":") statement does it still make sense to use ternary operators ?

Comment: 1. Define `var letc;` outside of the fn
2. Now you can use the 2nd line as `if (letr === " ") return (letc = " ");`

Encapsulating with parens sets `letc` to a single space and returns the single space to the fn's return statement - thus `letc === " "` and the fn also returns " " (which would be a truthy result to whatever interprets it.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't declare a variable for the result, just return the value. Example:

```
function myFunction(letr) {
  if (letr === " ") return " ";
  if (letr === "x") return "X";
  if (letr === "y") return "Y";
  return "neither";
}
```

You can also use the conditional operator:

```
function myFunction(letr) {
  return letr === " " ? " " :
    letr === "x" ? "X" :
    letr === "y" ? "Y" :
    "neither";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function myFunction(letr) {
    if (letr === " ") return { letc : " " };

    // ... other checks on letr that will return other values for letc
}
```

Comment: Oh ok thx ! I thought that in a "single line" if statement you didn't have to use { and } ?

Comment: I think that would be returning an object with property `letc` having the value `' '`.

Comment: @Zhihao indeed, what is a var if not an `Object` reference?

Comment: @AwakeZoldiek: The { and } are not for a code block, it's an object literal.

Answer (score 1):

Once you return, the function will be terminated and get the value out for the caller

```
function myFunction(letr) {
    var letc = " ";
    //Do some thing wit letc;
    if (letr === " ") return letr ;
    // ... other checks on letr that will return other values for letc
}
```